# Issues with css 2-d box flipping

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble with some css. I am trying to create a css flipping effect.  With what I have right now, it does not show what I have on the front service of my card. Only the back.  So essentially a card flips over 180 degrees, but it doesn't properly change.  Could anybody take a look at this for me? I would greatly appreciate it!

This is my html

```css
.flip3D {
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.flip3D > .front {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
  background: black;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-backface-visiblity: hidden;
  backface-visiblity: hidden;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
  transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
.flip3D > .back {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
  background: blue;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-backface-visiblity: hidden;
  backface-visiblity: hidden;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
  transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
.flip3D:hover > .front {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flip3D:hover > .back {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip3D">
  <div class="front">Box1 - Front</div>
  <div class="back">Box1 - Back</div>
</div>
<div class="flip3D">
  <div class="front">Box2 - Front</div>
  <div class="back">Box2 - Back</div>
</div>
<div class="flip3D">
  <div class="front">Box3 - Front</div>
  <div class="back">Box3 - Back</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo. `backface-visiblity` should be `backface-visibility`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this: `backface-visibility: hidden;`

> The backface-visibility property defines whether or not an element should be visible when not facing the screen. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_backface-visibility.asp

Edit: you need to apply that style to `.back`

Edit: it's misspelled. Check your spelling

Comment: obv. not in the correct place. I clarified my answer

Comment: He has it in the back class.

Comment: HA, there it is.  Now I almost feel bad I didn't catch that. Thank you so much for finding that for me!

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)